# Create a directory tree from dropbox api delta using the paths

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I found the question How to convert a file path into treeview?, but I'm not sure how to get the desired result in JavaScript:

I'm trying to turn an array of paths into a JSON tree:

```
 var paths = [
        "/org/openbmc/UserManager/Group",
        "/org/stackExchange/StackOverflow",
        "/org/stackExchange/StackOverflow/Meta",
        "/org/stackExchange/Programmers",
        "/org/stackExchange/Philosophy",
        "/org/stackExchange/Religion/Christianity",
        "/org/openbmc/records/events",
        "/org/stackExchange/Religion/Hinduism",
        "/org/openbmc/HostServices",
        "/org/openbmc/UserManager/Users",
        "/org/openbmc/records/transactions",
        "/org/stackExchange/Religion/Islam",
        "/org/openbmc/UserManager/Groups",
        "/org/openbmc/NetworkManager/Interface"
    ];
```

I want to have json structure like below using the folder paths.

```
        var xyz = [{
            "path": "photos",
            "name": "photos",
            "children": [
              {
                "path": "photos/summer",
                "name": "summer",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "path": "photos/summer/june",
                    "name": "june",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "path": "photos/summer/june/windsurf",
                        "name": "windsurf",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "path": "photos/winter",
                "name": "winter",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "path": "photos/winter/january",
                    "name": "january",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "path": "photos/winter/january/ski",
                        "name": "ski",
                      },
                      {
                        "path": "photos/winter/january/snowboard",
                        "name": "snowboard",
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
    }];
```

I have used below function but it's not working

```
var parsePathArray = function(paths) {
var parsed = [];
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var position = parsed;
    var split = paths[i].split('/');
    for (var j = 0; j < split.length; j++) {
        if (split[j] !== "") {
            if (typeof position[split[j]] === 'undefined')
                position[split[j]] = {};
            position.children = [position[split[j]]];
            position.name = split[j];
            position = position[split[j]];

        }
    }
}
return parsed;
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Do you know how to use `.split("/")` to go from a string to an array? Do you know how to create an object by looping over an array? Do you know how to nest and merge objects?

Comment: i have used split method and tried nested objects too

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: I wrote this answer because it's a fun exercise. I'm still disappointed in you for not trying and not taking the time to explain *what it is* you don't understand...**

---

I didn't follow your exact format so you'll have to try to understand how it's done instead of being able to copy the code and leave :)

I'll touch upon each step briefly to not risk explaining what you already know.

### Step 1:

Go from a list of strings to a list of arrays:

```
["a/1", "a/2", "b/1"] -> [["a", "1"], ["a", "2"], ["b", "1"]]
```

We use `String.prototype.slice` to remove the prepended "/" and `String.prototype.split` with your folder delimiter to convert to an array: `path.split("/")`

### Step 2

Loop over each folder and add the folder to an object.

```
[["a", "1"], ["a", "2"], ["b", "1"]] -> { a: { 1: {}, 2: {} }, b: { 1: {} } }
```

We use a reducer that accesses an object using bracket notation `obj[key]` instantiating new folder objects and returning the deepest location along the way.

### Step 3

Recursively loop over the keys of your object and convert to a specified format:

```
{ a: { 1: { } } -> { name: "a", path: [], children: [ /* ... */ ] }
```

We take a list of keys, which are folder names, using `Object.keys`. Recursively call for each nested object.

---

Please, update your answer with the *specific step you have trouble with* which allows others to help as well, and me to describe the step in more detail.

```js
const pathStrings = ["/org/openbmc/UserManager/Group", "/org/stackExchange/StackOverflow", "/org/stackExchange/StackOverflow/Meta", "/org/stackExchange/Programmers", "/org/stackExchange/Philosophy", "/org/stackExchange/Religion/Christianity", "/org/openbmc/records/events", "/org/stackExchange/Religion/Hinduism", "/org/openbmc/HostServices", "/org/openbmc/UserManager/Users", "/org/openbmc/records/transactions", "/org/stackExchange/Religion/Islam", "/org/openbmc/UserManager/Groups", "/org/openbmc/NetworkManager/Interface"];

const paths = pathStrings
    .map(str => str.slice(1))       // remove first "/"
    .map(str => str.split("/"));

// Mutates map!
const mergePathInToMap = (map, path) => {
    path.reduce(
        (loc, folder) => (loc[folder] = loc[folder] || {}, loc[folder]),
        map      
    );

    return map;
};

// Folder structure as { folderName: folderContents }
const folderMap = paths.reduce(mergePathInToMap, {});

// Go from 
//   { folderName: folderContents }
// to a desired format like 
//   { name: folderName, children: [contents] }
const formatStructure = (folder, path) => {
    return Object
        .keys(folder)
        .map(k => ({ 
            name: k,
            path: path,
            children: formatStructure(folder[k], path.concat(k))
        }))
    
}

console.log(
    JSON.stringify(
        formatStructure(folderMap, []),
        null,
        2
    )
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I cannot post what I have done it's giving me indentation error,